How is quantum entanglement detected experimentally?
What type of detector was used to detect entanglement of different systems, for example, photons?
Are there new detectors being made now?
What technique is used for this detection?

Some comments removed. Please remember to write an answer, not a comment, if you want to answer a question.

Ok, no comments :-) (....)

The original way to detect entanglement was to test Bell's inequality. (That is what Alain Aspect & co. got their Nobel prize for.) It is done by preparing entangled photons with spontaneous parametric down-conversion. For photons that are entangled in polarization one needs type II phase matching. The two entangled photons are then sent through two polarizers with varying orientations. After the polarizers, the photons are detected in coincidence using a coincidence counter.
The detectors are ideally photon-number-resolving detectors that can tell how many photons are detected, but these detector are only now beginning to be developed. So, without access to photon-number-resolving detectors, one can use detectors that are sensitive enough to measure single photons, such as avalanche photodiodes, and then reduce the down-conversion efficiency so that the the probability for the production of more than pair of photons is very low.
This is still probably the most widely used way to test entanglement, but there are other ways, such as full quantum state tomography.

Single photon detectors have existed since the 1930s, even though their quantum efficiency was low (in the 10% range). That does not matter to coincidence experiments. We are simply losing most of our useful events, but when coincidence occurs, it's still a valid measurement. We just have to correct our statistics for the quantum efficiency. The bigger question is why these experiments are even necessary. They don't tell us anything new about quantum mechanics that we haven't known, already.

Nice answer! (+1) Could you give a rough ballpark cost for doing this sort of entanglement demonstration for e.g. as a DIY or high school physics project, assuming no prior equipment/material?

@FlatterMann The point of experiments is to test knowledge. In circumstances where a theory makes a clear prediction, if you do the experiment and it contradicts the theory that creates a problem. This problem might be solved by a new theory or by finding a flaw in the experiment or your interpretation of it. So you learn something new, either you have to come up with a new theory or you improve your understanding of how to do experiments. If the experiment doesn't contradict the predictions then you have learned something about what sort of experiments are worth doing.

@alanf If we ever found a Bell-type experiment that would violate quantum mechanics, then we would have an experiment that manifestly violates relativity in addition. There is, of course, nothing wrong with searches for Lorentz or Poincare symmetry violation, but then let's call it that and optimize the experiment for that purpose. Bell type experiments are about as error-ridden as one can make a physics experiment. They don't satisfy any of the quality criteria of a precision exclusion test/null experiment.

@James It is difficult to give such an cost estimate because prices can vary a lot. However, the equipment tends to be rather expensive. Even the little nonlinear crystal is in my experience extremely expensive. So perhaps it is not exactly in the budget of a high school or DIY project.

@FlatterMann The violation of Bell's inequality does not violate relativity. Bell introduced two assumptions for the derivation of the inequality. One is locality which is related to relativity. The other one is a unique reality which does not have anything to do with relativity. QM implies that the latter assumption is not valid. If you want to know more about what this "unique reality" means, ask a question on Physics SE.

@flippiefanus thank you. I was just wondering about this... considering that crystals can be grown from practically any type of aqueous salt solutions, i.e. there are nearly infinite number of possible crystal types... shouldn't there be many more crystals that can do parametric down conversions other than BBo crystals?

@flippianus These are purely philosophical terms. Nature knows nothing about them. Nature only knows quantum mechanics. No matter how many experiments you do, you will never find anything else. We know the correct theory, already, and we know precisely what it predicts for Bell's formulas. If you don't trust quantum mechanics, then you need to come up with more precise atomic physics experiments. If you don't trust relativity, then you will probably have to look at cosmological signals (neutrinos/gravitational waves/UHE cosmic rays).

@James Not all crystals have large enough nonlinear coefficients to make them useful, but there a few that do. Have a look at https://www.rp-photonics.com/nonlinear_crystal_materials.html

@flippiefanus thank you. I am quite interested to perhaps do a part of the experiment, supposing a BBO or similar crystal can be sourced, in which 2 photoresistors placed at the 2 down-converted angles (after passing through frequency filter for filtering unrelated ambient wavelengths) should be able to detect the 2 "beams" of down-converted light, even though demonstrating any entanglement structure is not possible?

@flippiefanus A crystal like BBO can only down-convert a very specific/narrow range of input light frequency, and the output is also a very specific/narrow frequency of output light, right?

@James No, with type I phase matching, you would get a rainbow of different wavelengths spread out as a function of down-conversion angle. The two correlated photons would have wavelengths and angles that are related to the pump wavelength through momentum-energy conservation via the phase matching condition. OK this is more complicated than one can really explain well in a comment. Why don't you formulate a question in a post?

@flippiefanus thank you. I'd rather not as very few posts on entanglement are answered well / in depth, and often the result is a free for all brawl...  :) As you clearly know more about this area, could you perhaps formulate a proper technical question about the experimental setup for SPDC, please?
